# p2os error- setup failed

Tags: ros, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use p2os to control the Amigobot. I am now using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo. The Amigobot is connected to my laptop via USB port. I have successfully installed the p2os-purdue. But when I try `rosrun p2os_driver p2os_driver`. I have the following error:

```
fan@Fan--PC:~/test_ws$ rosrun p2os_driver p2os_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
[ INFO] [1438630934.277844305]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
[ INFO] [1438630934.314938066]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
...
[ INFO] [1438630935.716930912]: SYNC0
[ INFO] [1438630935.917268096]: turning off NONBLOCK mode...
[ INFO] [1438630936.117623204]: SYNC1
[ INFO] [1438630936.518107007]: SYNC2
[ INFO] [1438630937.118764772]: Done.
   Connected to SUNY_509, a Pioneer Amigo-sh
[ERROR] [1438630939.522397962]: p2os setup failed...
```

I have read the similar problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/198667/p2os-setup-failed-for-hydro/). It seems that I have same problem with sealguy77. But after I try `sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyUSB0` , I still get the same error: `[ERROR] [1438631499.971642893]: p2os setup failed...`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215157/p2os-error--setup-failed/) by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-08-03**:
Hm... Interesting. I'll take a look at this later. What version of p2os are you using?

**Comment by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on 2015-08-03**:
It is 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies! There is an issue in the code. I have just fixed it, and will be re-releasing p2os for jade. Please use [the git version of the code](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os). The updated binaries should be available on the next update cycle.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on 2015-08-05**:
Thank you! It works now : )

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-08-05**:
Glad to hear it! I made a pretty bizarre error, if you were curious. I had: `if (!p2os->Setup()){ /** exit on error **/}` But needed to have `if (p2os->Setup()){/** exit on error **/}`. I will be changing the API, as this is just unnecessarily confusing...  XD